# Which user will currentUser will return among many users currently Logged In?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Despite there will be many user currently logged in my firebase, how it determines a particular person is logged in or not with just an instance of FirevaseAuth?

```
 FirebaseAuth ref = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 ref.currentUser;
//which user will be returned amoung many logged in user currently using the `app?`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Auth SDK only tracks the single user signed into the instance of the app where the code is running.  That's what you get from `currentUser`.  The SDK doesn't know anything else about any other users using the app on other devices.

Comment: I am still confused yet. Let's consider these condition: (1) I have app with only sign in option and shows user Id if signed in in just one page. (2) I singed in and re run the code. will it still consider me as signed in and show the user Id ? If yes, then how? Got puzzled.

Comment: Yes, users are persistently signed in until you sign them out.

Comment: does it means that from the point where I logged in even if I am using new instance, it will return same user till we log out, right?

Comment: It will be the same user until they are signed out.

Comment: Thank you , I got my answer.